# Looking for 3rd party Qt Gantt Chart component

Tags: c++, qt, gantt-chart

I'm looking for a Qt Gantt Chart GUI component or at least the beginnings of one. I've looked the web over so this is my last stop before creating one for myself. I'm capable of realizing this type of component myself but would prefer to dedicate my time to more domain specific development problems if at all possible.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you can download a trial version. But I thinks it's rather expensive:

KDGantt follows the same pricing model and license agreement that Nokia uses. Per developer / platform licensing, each developer licensed to use KDGantt on a certain platform may use the software on any number of computers running this platform, but other developers working on the same computers may not, unless they have their own licenses. There are no runtime/royalty fees for applications built and deployed using KDGantt. You may ship the binary library together with any number of your application(s) for the platform your license is assigned to.

One (1) KDGantt license for single platform ----------------- $1600.00 US
UNIX/Linux or Mac or Windows, chose one platform

One (1) KDGantt license for duo platform -------------------- $ 2400.00. US
UNIX/Linux or Mac or Windows, chose two platforms

One (1) KDGantt license for trio platform --------------------- $ 3200.00. US
UNIX/Linux, Mac and Windows, all three platforms

Comment: Yeah rather expensive, we have custom control dev experience here so we may just in house it but the price listing is very helpful thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Would this do it? http://www.ics.com/products/qt/kdgantt/. Found via a quick Google search.

Comment: Yeah I saw this one but there are no prices and haven't receive a quote reply... Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you also have a look at the VARCHART XGantt control from NETRONIC. This control is around on the market for a long time, it is proven in mission critical applications, and very feature-rich. Please note: my answer is biased as I work for NETRONIC. I also openly share that we sell at higher prices than all tools mentioned above; and that is for a reason.

Have a look at our Gantt chart offerings. If you like what you see, please send us an email to mailto:sales@netronic.com. Please refer to stackoverflow and ask that this email will get forwarded to Martin. He will get in contact to you to evaluate the potential of creating a complementary rapid prototype.

btw - A Gantt is typically more complex than many people assume. From talking to many of our clients (both software developers and end users) I know that using a proven control turns into tangible time-to-market benefits.

Does this help you although it is a vendor answer?